# PHP function and HTML output parse error

Tags: php, syntax-error

There is something wrong with this code, I cant make it go trough... the situation is that

the difficulty-meter needs to be checked , if it is filled, execute a mix of HTML and PHP. I'm learning php and got stuck in this functions...
Im using WP and WPML to translate that's why I add the     `-__e('Difficulty', 'projectname')':` as a string. I get a error ,

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'tpage' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages/46/d448593520/htdocs/wp-content/themes/site/document.php on line 218
```

My full code is

```
<?php
// CHECK IF DIFFICULTY FIELD EMPTY
$diffcheck = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-difficulty-meter', true);
if ( $diffcheck) {
echo "<ul class="tpage-list">
<li>' 
-__e('Difficulty', 'projectname')':
'</li><li>'
types_render_field('difficulty-meter', array('output'=>'html','class'=>'tpage-difficulty'))
'</li></ul>";})

}
else {
// Show Nothing
}
// END
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax highlighting shows your error: it's a quoting issue. You have to escape your double quotes inside of your string:

```
echo "<ul class=\"tpage-list\">
```

or use single quotes:

```
echo "<ul class='tpage-list'>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do it right?

Comment: Um, that's exactly what my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

To complete what John Conde said, this part make no sense:

```
echo "<ul class="tpage-list">
<li>' 
-__e('Difficulty', 'projectname')':
'</li><li>'
types_render_field('difficulty-meter', array('output'=>'html','class'=>'tpage-difficulty'))
'</li></ul>";})
```

Lets go through it:

```
// You have to keep track of concatenation. You started the string with ", you can't use it except to end string (or if you use \ like John Conde said)

// After the li: it seem like you wanted to add the value of the Difficulty thing, so you have to end your string and concaten it with a .

// Back to the strings and concaten it again to add the type render, since the string is now started with a ', I use a ' to end it
echo "
   <ul class='tpage-list'>
       <li>".-__e('Difficulty', 'projectname').':</li>
       <li>'.
            types_render_field('difficulty-meter', array('output'=>'html','class'=>'tpage-difficulty'))
       .'</li>
   </ul>';
```

I don't really see why you had a }) at the end, so I took it out

Comment: thanks now I understood 4 ever the quoting and how to use it. thanks zeppo :)